# Google chrome incognito's slow-down behavior

Tags: google-chrome

I wonder if anyone could help me explain this weird thing. I've used Google Chrome incognito mode for a few days, but I observe that it causes the entire performance to slow down and often time unresponsive and even crashes for no reason.

Answer (score 12):

Ubuntu 16.04 TLS
Chrome 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit)

Had same issue with incognito tab. If smth opened in incognito, others instances of chrome start lagging/crashing/not responding. 
According to this article [Google Chrome Forum](http://Google%20Chrome%20Forum) step 1 helped me in solving this issue.

> 1. Uncheck Use hardware acceleration (Menu> Settings> Show Advanced Settings > System menu).

After this everything is smooth and flying :)

Comment: Thank you! I was having a similar issue with Ubuntu 18 / Chrome 86 and unchecking Hardware Acceleration fixed things.

Comment: Was experiencing the exact same issue. Launching a Chrome Incognito instance would slow down all other, non-incognito instances.

Ubuntu 20.04 + Chrome 87.0.4280.66

Disabling the "Use hardware acceleration" option fixed things back.

This issue was posted 4 years ago... and this is still happening?

Comment: But why is this an issue? What if I need hardware acceleration to use certain web apps?

Comment: Just confirming that this is still an issue, and that it can be reproduced on latest Chromium in Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Still an issue in 22.02. Disabling hardware acceleration as describe in the answer helped.